# Check if X is a multiple of Y, where Y may be zero

Tags: rust

I have two numbers, X and Y, and I want to assert that X is a multiple of Y -- i.e., I want to assert that there exists some arbitrary integer n such that Y * n == X.

If Y is guaranteed to be greater than zero, I can write

```
assert!(x % y == 0)
```

But in my case, Y may be zero. If Y is zero, then X must also be zero, so I could write

```
if y == 0 {
    assert!(x == 0);
} else {
    assert!(x % y == 0);
}
```

But this is 5 lines long and has two branches vs. the assert's single branch. Is it possible to do this in one line in an elegant way?

Comment: I don't know rust, but `assert!(x==y || x%y==0)`?

Comment: x == y || x%y == 0 is great, make this an answer and i'll mark it

Comment: Note that that will panic if `y == 0` but `x` is nonzero. `x == y || ( y != 0 && x % y == 0)` would work.

Comment: Good point -- the "assertion will fail" but it'll fail with a divide by zero error rather than a helpful error message

Answer (score 5):

[`if` is an expression in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/if.html), so you could write

```
assert_eq!(0, if y == 0 { x } else { x % y });
```

As mentioned in the comment, you could also write

```
assert!(y == 0 && x == 0 || x % y == 0);
```

but the `if` expression approach is more general.

You could also [use `checked_rem`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_rem) so that `x.checked_rem(0) == None`, but that is not going to be simpler than an `if` expression.

```
assert_eq!(0, x.checked_rem(y).unwrap_or(x));
```

Comment: `assert_eq!(0, x % if y == 0 { 1 } else { y });` looks invalid to me, if `y == 0` then the result would always be 0. since `mod 1` is always equivalent to 0.

Comment: @AleksanderFular OK. Deleted that.